# お隣さんになって早々, 申し訳ないですうぅ~ means?

Tags: translation

I can read all of them but I'm not really sure what it means and what my friend is sorry for?

Is she saying she's sorry to be my neighbour...?

p.s we're playing a multiplayer game when she said this if that helps

Comment: Did you help her?

Comment: What you want to know is NOT expressed in that line.  You will need to provide more context or tell us what happened immediately before she said it.  As of now, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @l'électeur I disagree. It _can_ be translated. The context will help pinpoint what exactly she meant or was referring to by it.

Comment: I think the sentence is a little bit fuzzy because when the op helped her, 申し訳ないです means thanks but when she caused the op trouble, it's a apologizing. So I asked the OP like " Did you help her?" at the beginning.

Comment: Yes I did so I guess she meant that as a thank you rather than an apology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Japanese, apologies are sometimes expressions of humility, that can be replaced with a "thank you". Essentially, apologizing is for whatever effort the listener expended (or will expend) on behalf of the speaker.

So it is likely that the neighbor of yours apologized for something you did to help her ([as suggested in comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29658/%E3%81%8A%E9%9A%A3%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%97%A9%E3%80%85-%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%86%E3%81%85-means#comment61584_29658)), or something you will or are expected to do. It depends a lot on the context.

For example, if this person moved into your neighborhood and shortly afterwards asked for help, or requested backup, resources or whatever game-mechanic is used in this multiplayer universe that is directly beneficial to the receiver and non-beneficial (or not necessarily beneficial) to the giver, it would be appropriate to thank the giver. It can also be appropriate to apologize to the giver, to show more humility.

So an effective translation might be:

> "Sorry to be such a burden on you right after moving in next door!"

or:

> "Thank you for helping me right after I moved in next door!"

or even:

> "Thanks in advance!"